# Explicitly Asking for Default Move Constructor Does not Work?

Tags: c++11

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

class Bar {
    uint32_t m_value;
public:
    Bar(const uint32_t value) : m_value(value) {
    }
};

class Foo {
    Bar* m_p_bar;
    uint32_t m_value;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
public:
    /*
    Foo(Foo&& from) {
        m_p_bar = from.m_p_bar;
        m_value = from.m_value;
        from.m_p_bar = nullptr;
    }
    */
    Foo(const uint32_t value) : m_value(value) {
        m_p_bar = new Bar(value);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    foos.emplace_back(8);
}
```

Compiler complains:

```
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/vector:66,
                 from test_implicit_func.cpp:2:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Foo*>; _ForwardIterator = Foo*]’:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:307:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Foo*>; _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Tp = Foo]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:329:2:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Foo*; _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Allocator = std::allocator<Foo>]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:474:3:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int}; _Tp = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator<Foo>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = Foo*]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:121:4:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int}; _Tp = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator<Foo>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = Foo&]’
test_implicit_func.cpp:34:21:   required from here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:127:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
  127 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
      |                                                                        ^~~~~
```

I noticed that for some reason, I need to define my own move constructor for `Foo`.  By explicitly asking the compiler to use the default one (i.e. `Foo(Foo&&) = default;`), it doesn't work.  However, if I ask the compiler to use all the implicit ones (i.e. removing `Foo(const Foo&) = delete;` `Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;` `Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;` `Foo(Foo&&) = default;`), then compiler doesn't complain.

My question is why explicitly asking compiler to use the default move constructor here doesn't work but it works in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62752286/9784373).  And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003459/9784373) suggests I could ask for a default version if it is implicitly removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let the compiler use the implicitly defined "big 5" you will have problems with leaks and double free:s.

You need to make the move constructor `public` and you need to `delete` the pointer in the destructor. You also need to make sure not to leave the pointer in the *moved-from* object.

```
#include <utility> // exchange

class Foo {
    Bar* m_p_bar;
    uint32_t m_value;

public:
    Foo(const uint32_t value) : 
        m_p_bar(new Bar(value)),
        m_value(value) 
    {}

    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;

    Foo(Foo&& rhs) :
        m_p_bar(std::exchange(rhs.m_p_bar, nullptr)),  // put a nullptr in rhs
        m_value(rhs.m_value)
    {}
    Foo& operator=(Foo&& rhs) {
        std::swap(m_p_bar, rhs.m_p_bar);     // let rhs destroy our current Bar
        m_value = rhs.m_value;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Foo() { delete m_p_bar; }               // destroy it
};
```

A better idea would be to use a `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` - or to not use a pointer at all.

Comment: ah, I didn't notice I implicitly made `Foo(Foo&&) = default;` private.  That's the issue.  Since the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator are deleted, I believe that they don't have to be private (I used to declare them private without implementation before C++11 to trigger compiler error if anywhere of the code attempts to make a copy).  The double frees you mentioned could happen if I don't have copy constructor and the copy assignment operator deleted and then somewhere in the code actually makes a copy, right?

Comment: @HCSF I need to retrecat my first comment. Does my answer actually answer your question?

Comment: Yes definitely.  Let me accept.  Just confused with the double frees

Comment: @HCSF The double free:s comes in if you _do_ indeed start `delete`ing without managing the pointer properly. Two objects will "own" it if you let a `default` constructor of any kind manage it.